# WP site URL changed to have HTTPS but still homepage does not redirect

Tags: htaccess, homepage, home-url

I've changed the WP site URL to include `https://www` & it's been a while.  Entire site is correctly reflecting it.

[image]

But unless I add following in .htaccess, the home page does not redirect

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

But, in case htaccess goes corrupt & gets regenerated, it skips this part. 
Then  `http://domain.com` does not redirect to `http://wwww.domain.com`

Even if that part was added within

```
# BEGIN WordPress
here
# END WordPress
```

The problem is only with the homepage. Nothing else.

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: Hi. I am not sure about the exact scenario whether the site in picture is behind load balancer or not. But I think the 'Notes' section on [this Codex documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_ssl) page may be helpful, so please take a look.

Comment: Thanks so much @ItsMePN for pointing to correct info. Yes, the site is behind Cloudflare. & the problem is now resolved. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into similar issues. Here is what worked, as suggested by ItsMePN.

If your site is on a loadbalancer such as **CloudFlare**, `is_ssl()` doesn't work.

Neither did it work for me on a site hosted on "Cloudways + Digital Ocean"

Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/webaware/4688802 for `force-ssl-url-scheme.php` you need to download & upload it under `wp-content/plugins` & activate it.

Worked perfectly.